# Rotation solid generated by $\sin{x}$ around y axis

Tags: real-analysis, integration, volume, rotations

I have to determine the volume generated by rotation around y axis of $y=\sin{(x)}$ for $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ delimited by the segment on line $y=1$ up to $x=\pi/2$.

The solid that I have to rotate so is

[image]

so the formula of rotation of this kind of solid si given by:
$$V=\pi\int_{0}^{1}(f(y))^2dy=\pi\int_{0}^{1}\arcsin^2{y}\,\,dy=\frac{1}{4}\pi(\pi^2-8)$$
with x=f(y)

**Question:** am I right in considering this formula and so the inverse of sine?

Comment: The notation $f(y)$ is a bit strange. But everything appears correct.

Comment: I'd think of it as $f^{-1}(y)$, not $f(y)$, and it should be squared (which you take care of in the next step), but yes, the radius of each disk is $\sin^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: Your factor of $\pi$ went missing.

Comment: Thanks to all of you! I have corrected...now do you think it is correct?